# Dynamics Variable (variable++) in Append function DOM Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
function add_fullboard_dalam_kota(){
    var data='<?php echo $data; ?>';
    var tambah=1;
    var txt=1;
    $("#fullboard_dalam_kota").append('<tr align="center" valign="middle"bgcolor="#E4E4E4">'
      +'<td width="19%" ><input name="penyelenggara[]" type="text" id="'+tambah+'" onchange="showUser(this.value)"></td>'
      +'<td width="19%" ><div id="'+txt+'"><b></b></div>'  
      +'</td>'
      +'<td width="19%" ><input name="jumlah_peserta[]" type="text" id="jumlah_peserta[]"></td>'
      +'<td width="19%" ><input name="jumlah_hari[]" type="text" id="jumlah_hari[]"></td>'
      +'</tr>')


  tambah=tambah+1;
  txt=txt+1;

  alert(tambah);
```

My question is why the value of "tambah" variable is always 2? And how to make it dynamically added by 1 after one append() function called?

Comment: It is a local variable, you can move it to global scope to have tambah retain its value, or just count the `tr` in the table and increment by 1 if this is the only source of tr addition in your code.

Comment: Why are you assigning ids to repeated elements like that? What do you need the id for? (And note that the other inputs added by that function have hard-coded ids, which is creating invalid html given that id is supposed to be unique.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variable "tambah" outside of the function.

```
//Declare variable outside scope of fucn()
var tambah=1;

function add_fullboard_dalam_kota(){
    var data='<?php echo $data; ?>';
    var txt=1;
    $("#fullboard_dalam_kota").append('<tr align="center" valign="middle"bgcolor="#E4E4E4">'
      +'<td width="19%" ><input name="penyelenggara[]" type="text" id="'+tambah+'" onchange="showUser(this.value)"></td>'
      +'<td width="19%" ><div id="'+txt+'"><b></b></div>'  
      +'</td>'
      +'<td width="19%" ><input name="jumlah_peserta[]" type="text" id="jumlah_peserta[]"></td>'
      +'<td width="19%" ><input name="jumlah_hari[]" type="text" id="jumlah_hari[]"></td>'
      +'</tr>')

  tambah++;
  txt++;
  alert(tambah);
 }
```